# list operations for getting common elements in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a scenario where I am trying to find out the common items in a list and append a value accordingly

```
a_l = ['62', '63', '66', '67']
a_ls = ['66', '67']
```

now if there are common elements in a_ls from a_l then create a combined list with `status : 1` for the common items found and rest as `status : 0`.

This is what I have done.

```
non_comn_list = [item for item in a_l if item not in a_ls]
com_list = [item for item in a_l if item not in non_comn_list]
list = [{'a_id': a, 'status': 1} for a in com_list]
[list.append(val) for val in [{'a_id': a, 'status': 0} for a in non_comn_list]]
```

Current output :

```
[{'a_id': '62', 'status': 0}, {'a_id': '63', 'status': 0}, {'a_id': '66', 'status': 0}, {'a_id': '67', 'status': 0}]
```

desired output :

```
[{'a_id': '62', 'status': 0}, {'a_id': '63', 'status': 0}, {'a_id': '66', 'status': 1}, {'a_id': '67', 'status': 1}]
```

What am I doing wrong here ? any help woud be great

Comment: Even though it is giving you the wrong output, you have applied the brute force approach. If your file is big it is going to take a long time.

Comment: I cannot reproduce it. It runs fine. BTW, it is a bad practice to make a variable name same as built-in function (in your case, `list`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
a_l = ['62', '63', '66', '67']
a_ls = ['66', '67']
```

What about iterating over a big list and checking membership in a small list like below:

```
[{'a_id': el, 'status': 1 if el in a_ls else 0} for el in a_l]
```

and if the lists are big you can convert them to `sets` to optimize membership testing.

```
a_ls_set = set(a_ls)
[{'a_id': el, 'status': 1 if el in a_ls else 0} for el in a_l]
```

What happens if `a_ls` is bigger than `a_l`? this will solve that problem:

```
from collections import Counter

[{'a_id': a_id, 'status': 1 if count > 1 else 0} 
for a_id, count in Counter(a_l + a_ls).items()]
```

Comment: nice solution, but what happens if `len(a_l) < len(a_ls)` o_O

Comment: if statement can help to choose the smaller list for testing membership

Comment: @ Davit Tovmasyan, yup now its fine :D, just wanted to see complete answer

Answer (score 3):

On top of iterative approach- you can try with `set` and operations on them:

```py
import numpy as np

a_l = ['62', '63', '66', '67']
a_ls = ['66', '67']
i=set(a_l).intersection(set(a_ls))
d=np.bitwise_xor(set(a_l), set(a_ls))
lst=list(map(lambda x: dict(list(x)), zip(zip(["a_id"]*len(i), i),[("status", 1)]*len(i))))+list(map(lambda x: dict(list(x)), zip(zip(["a_id"]*len(d), d),[("status", 0)]*len(d))))
```

Outputs:

```py
[{'a_id': '66', 'status': 1}, {'a_id': '67', 'status': 1}, {'a_id': '62', 'status': 0}, {'a_id': '63', 'status': 0}]
```

Comment: Why use bitwise_xor on the sets? That doesn’t make much sense. Also, IMHO your expression for lst is a bit too complex/clever, to the point where it would not be possible to understand for someone new to Python.

Comment: Because - we need easy ```xor``` in here, and since the underlying object is ```set``` - we can do it bit-wise, that's the easiest & fastest way imo. About the complexity- I would say it's a set of few very basic python operations on lists/dicts/sets which as a whole might be difficult, but individually is pretty straightforward. Hence - I would have some reservations against elaborating on this solution, cause really- it's nothing tricky, if you talk it through step by step - it will be just description how ```dict```, ```map```, ```zip``` etc. works.

Comment: Why not just `set(a_l) ^ set(a_ls)` instead of depending on NumPy? Secondly I think a list comprehension would be a lot nicer than `list(map(lambda`?

Comment: I would consider moving also intersection to ```numpy``` tbh. Also - frankly speaking I didn't know you can do xor on sets directly. I will do some benchmarking to check which one is faster (same goes for ```map```).

Answer (score 1):

This is straightforward to do with `set`, a data structure which stores unique elements and has special operations to find the union (`|`) and intersection (`&`) of two sets:

```py
s_l = set(a_l)
s_ls = set(a_ls)
merged = s_l | s_ls
common = s_l & s_ls
result = [dict(a_id=v, status=int(v in common)) for v in merged]
```